# Apache Cordova in Visual Studio is not able to connect with Mac (remote build server)

Tags: macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015, ios-simulator, remote-access

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows computer and I want to simulate my app on a MacBook via remotebuild. But the VS Remote Agent Client is not able to connect:

If I try to establish a connection with security PIN, it says:
"An error occurred trying to acquire certificate from https// ..."

If I try to establish a connection without security PIN, it says:
"Unable to connect to remote iOS build server. Underlying exception: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

If I run Apache Cordova on the Mac, there aren't any problems. And also my Xamarin App works on the remote iOS simulator. So why is it not possible to run my Apache Cordova App there, too?

Maybe it is relevant to mention, that I do not have an Apple Developer Program Account.

Comment: Stop the remote agent on Mac and in a terminal run `remotebuild certificates reset` then `remotebuild certificates generate` and start remote build agent again. Also,please check the IOS Configurations under VS->tools->options->Tools for Apache Cordova.

Comment: I've updated the certificates already. But the iOS Configurations will not be set in Visual Studio, because of the error message described above. I also tried to pair the Mac in the VS Cross-Platform C++ configurations without success.

Comment: Check if this link can help:[Did you receive an error that relates to your certificate?](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#certificate).

Comment: I checked the Cordova CLI version of VS and Mac and they were different: VS had Cordova CLI 6.0.0 and the Mac Cordova Version is 6.2.0. I changed the VS Cordova version to 6.2.0, but that didn't help. Same connection error as usual... I use the IP addess to connect, so it's not a hostname problem. The firewall of the Mac is disabled.

Comment: Are you sure that you are configuring VS with the port that remotebuild is running on? We don't report a HTTP 403 anywhere (at least not at this point in the communication) so it looks like there may be another HTTP server listening on the port.

Can you try `curl http://<mac>:<port>` and `curl -k https://<mac>:<port>` and see what response you get? Also try `remotebuild saveconfig --port=9876` or some other unused port, then restart remotebuild and see if VS can connect to it on the new port.

Comment: The response is "(52) Empty reply from server"

Comment: I changed the port and also disabled the firewall of my Windows computer. But that didn't change anything, either...

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure, you MacBook and VS workstation both are in same network. Also verify using command prompt that MacBook's IP add
- Replace host name using IP address MacBook and try again.
- If this does not work then following are steps to reset remotebuild:
- first stop server using following command:
   `cntrl + c`

  1. Execute following command to reset remotebuild certificates:

     `remotebuild certificates reset`
  2. Run following to command to regenerate remotebuild server:

     `remotebuild certificates generate`
- here, new secure pin number will be generated.

  3. Following command to start remotebuild:

     `remotebuild`
- now try again, make sure 'Enable remote iOS processing' is true and 'Secure mode' is true and valid secure number is added.

Answer (score -2):

I will simulate my app using the Apache Ripple simulator for iOS and Android, although "Ripple doesn’t provide a complete simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities (plugins). It also doesn’t simulate specific browser versions for a particular platform." (https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/)
But it's better than nothing...